# Split one column to 3 columns--new scenario

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to split the data into three different categories. Since I found one scenario which is not been handling by the query used by me. Below is the query with couple of examples:

QUERY:-

```
with XYZ as (
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Antarctica, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arctic, Language: English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arigina, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION                                                   
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Language: German, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 8, Circuit: Canada Abcdef & dfasghi Network, Language(s): English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all                                    
  select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Biotechnology Xyzabc [National], Language(s): English, Words: 493' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Hijkl Wireless (sel-srvc), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: ching Kong, Language(s): Chinese (Traditional), Words: 414' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Major A.B. Marketing, Language(s): English, Words: 400'  as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Language: English, Multi Postings: ANJA-5I9EBF, Words: 343' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
)                                                  
SELECT SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
--regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \\[\\] \\&]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit1",
--regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\&]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\& \\.]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
NVL( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language\\(s\\):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\, (@"\Webcenter Postings|\b")]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e'), 
REGEXP_REPLACE( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, '(Language:.*), Words', 1, 1, 'e'), '[ ]*Language: '  )) AS "LanguageString",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Words:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words"
FROM XYZ;
```

---

`'Attachments: 1, Language: English, Multi Postings: ANJA-5I9EBF, Words: 343'`          --> this is the example where I am getting captured with some other words in language string . Instead of getting captured language as `English`, I am getting `English, Webcenter Postings: ANJA-5I9EBF` .

Note: This question is repeated couple of times in stack overflow, as i have the basic knowledge on Regex and the scenario found is new.

Answer (score 0):

When the first version was written, we assumed that there won't be anything between Language and Words. Now we should consider that the "Words" is not mandatory, and anything can come(?).

I changed how to parse languages but ended up a complex SQL which would be very hard to maintain:

```
with XYZ as (
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Antarctica, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arctic, Language: English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arigina, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION                                                   
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Language: German, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 8, Circuit: Canada Abcdef & dfasghi Network, Language(s): English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all                                    
  select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Biotechnology Xyzabc [National], Language(s): English, Words: 493' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Hijkl Wireless (sel-srvc), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: ching Kong, Language(s): Chinese (Traditional), Words: 414' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Major A.B. Marketing, Language(s): English, Words: 400'  as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Language: English, Multi Postings: ANJA-5I9EBF, Words: 343' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
)                                                  
SELECT SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\& \\.]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Words:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words",
LISTAGG( regexp_substr(v.value,'[^,.]*[^,]') , ',' )  OVER( PARTITION BY v.seq ) "SingleLanguages"
FROM XYZ,
LATERAL split_to_table(   regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language:.*' ), 'Language: ' ) v
QUALIFY v.index = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\& \\.]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Words:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words",
LISTAGG( regexp_substr(v.value,'.*[^ ]') , ',' )  OVER( PARTITION BY v.seq ) "Languages"
FROM XYZ,
LATERAL split_to_table(  regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language\\(s\\):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\, (@"\Webcenter Postings|\b")]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e'), 'Language (s): ' ) v
QUALIFY v.index = 1
;
```

I recommend you to consider using alternative approaches (i.e. using Spark) to parse this data.

Comment: Cant we use regex replace function to replace the "Multi Postings: ANJA-5I9EBF" to the existing logic

Comment: We can do it but then you would come with "Sinlge Posting" etc... The above code should parse Langue/Langue(s) for all cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple JavaScript UDF to find when it's captured key markers and suppress them. This UDF has a constant that would hold all potential delimiters in a key:value pair. In this case, it appears to be only ":", so you can change that constant. It shows multiple chars just in case it's needed.

```
create or replace function SUPPRESS_CAPTURED_KEY("value" string)
returns string
language javascript
immutable
as
$$
    const KEY_MARKERS = ":!@<>?";

    var out = value;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < KEY_MARKERS.length; i++) {
        out = stripWithBadChar(out, KEY_MARKERS.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
    return out;
    
    function stripWithBadChar(inVar, badChar) {
        var out = "";
        var lang = inVar.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < lang.length; i++) {
            if (lang[i].indexOf(badChar) == -1) {
                if (out.length > 0) out += ",";
                out += lang[i];
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
$$

;
with XYZ as (
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Antarctica, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arctic, Language: English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arigina, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION                                                   
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Language: German, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 8, Circuit: Canada Abcdef & dfasghi Network, Language(s): English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all                                    
  select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Biotechnology Xyzabc [National], Language(s): English, Words: 493' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Hijkl Wireless (sel-srvc), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: ching Kong, Language(s): Chinese (Traditional), Words: 414' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Major A.B. Marketing, Language(s): English, Words: 400'  as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Language: English, Multi Postings: ANJA-5I9EBF, Words: 343' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
)                                                  
SELECT SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
--regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \\[\\] \\&]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit1",
--regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\&]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\& \\.]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
suppress_captured_key(NVL( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language\\(s\\):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\, (@"\Webcenter Postings|\b")]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e'),
    REGEXP_REPLACE( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, '(Language:.*), Words', 1, 1, 'e'), '[ ]*Language: '  ))) AS "LanguageString",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Words:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words"
FROM XYZ;
```